# Is there a tool for PHP to find files that attempt to use undefined functions?

Tags: php

We have a large legacy codebase, and trying to find where a function is defined is quite the task. Luckily, modern IDEs have this covered. What *isn't* clear, however, is how (or, indeed, *if*) a file has already been included.

Our old-style code will often have a group of related functions in a single file, and prefix each function with the filename (so login_validate() will be in login.php).

#### example.php

```
<?php

require_once 'functions/login.php';
require_once 'functions/validate.php';
validate_something(); // Uses function defined in validate.php
echo user_login(), PHP_EOL; // user.php must have been included *somewhere* for this to work, but where?!
```

My question is: **is there a tool that can scan PHP files and tell me which files will fail to execute, due to unresolved functions?**

Note: Using PHP's built-in lint checker (`php -l`) doesn't catch this case.

Comment: This is why OOP classes with an autoloader are so useful

Comment: Just to confirm: when you say "PHP Lint doesn't check this", are you referring to PHP's built-in command-line lint checker (`php -l`) or the third-party tool called [PHPLint](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/)?

Comment: @MarkBaker yes, our modern code doesn't suffer from this, but we don't live in an ideal world where all code is up-to-date with best (or even good) practice.

Comment: @SDC I actually meant `php -l`, I wasn't aware of PHPLint as a standalone tool.

Answer (score 0):

[PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) is what I'd recommend. (In general, not just for this use.)

With it, you're able to do exactly this by running a project wide inspection. From the toolbar menu:

`Code > Run Inspection by Name`

Then a dialog will pop up asking for the type of inspection. Type in `undefined function` and hit enter. Then the next dialog will ask for the scope to run the inspection in, which is most likely your Whole project.

Comment: I *really* dislike Java on the desktop, and as a PHP user, I'm very cheap… ;)

Comment: Ok fair enough. Although if you wanted to you could just download the free 30 day trial for this purpose and be Java free again in no time! ;) (p.s. I'm in no way affiliated with Jetbrains)